# Android AlertDialog box not showing, no errors

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

UPDATE: Completely rewrote question to clarify

I'm creating an AlertDialog to tell the user to hold on (app hasn't crashed) while the app pulls a list of Apps, sorts it, and puts it into a listview.  If I run the AlertDialog code on its own, it works.  But combined with the other code, it just does nothing. No error, just doesn't appear.  The list of Apps pops up just fine 9 seonds later.

```
    public void onClick_ChooseApp(View v) {
        TextView desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.AppChoice_Desc);

        AlertDialog waitBox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.wait_dialog, null))
                .show();

        final ArrayList<PackageInfo> pkgs = quickSort(new ArrayList(getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0)));
        for (int i=pkgs.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            Boolean criteria = (pkgs.get(i).applicationInfo.icon==0);
            if (criteria) {
                pkgs.remove(i);
            }
        }
        waitBox.dismiss();

        AlertDialog chooser = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setAdapter(new AppAdapter(this, pkgs), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String appName = pkgs.get(which).applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
                        Logg.d("selected " + which + "; " + appName);
                        chosenApp.setText(appName);
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("ChosenAppPkg", pkgs.get(which).packageName).apply();
                        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("ChosenAppName", appName).apply();
                    }
                })
                .show();
   }
```

**wait_dialog.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ProgressBar
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:id="@+id/marker_progress"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_medium_material"
        android:text="Loading List of Apps"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try setting a positive button and both callback methods for your AlertDialog and let me know if it works.

Comment: Your last code is working fine.. I have tried and there is no any issue. Have apply this method `onClick_ChooseApp` to your button in your `xml` file??

Comment: Are you sure the code is getting called? What happens if you put it in your activities onCreate method?

Comment: I rewrote the question to include all the code after. It appears it's the code afterwards which is causing the problem

Comment: In your method your calling two dialogs at same time. Instead of using this way you can call your another alert dialog on dismissal of your first alert dialog click on its positive button or negative button.

Comment: @PiyushGupta I just tried moving waitBox.dismiss to before I create chooser.  That didn't work.

Comment: You need to dismiss on click of its negative button.

Comment: Ideally it has no negative button. It's just got a progress dialog and a "don't panic" message.  It should dismiss as soon as the quicksort and cleanup is done.

Comment: But simentuneoulsy you can't open two dialog's. For that you need to dismiss with it some specific time or some specific progress.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this, did you know there is a ProgressDialog for this purpose, but it also should not be used. Read this http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html

Comment: @ElefantPhace I'm not sure where you're saying it shouldn't be used.  I added the XML code to the question so you can see.  I'm using an indeterminate activity circle.  Yes, I have text which apparently is a design no-no, but that's really more of an aesthetic question, not a technical one.

Comment: For your requirement simply use `ProgressDialog`

Comment: Per Google progressdialogs or creating your own should be avoided. Instead think about moving your loading circle into your actual chooser alertdialog then showing the content once its loaded.

Comment: @ElefantPhace I'm fine with doing that, but my whole problem is that the first dialog never shows.  The second one does, but something with the sorting and cleanup code is interfering with showing the dialog beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with an ASyncTask.  The problem seems to have been that the original AlertDialog hadn't finished creating when the very cpu-intensive quicksort began.  ASyncTask separated them into different threads which solved the problem.

```
 public void onClick_ChooseApp(View v) {
    final Context mThis = this;

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<PackageInfo>> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<PackageInfo>>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(mThis);
            pd.setMessage("Loading List of Apps");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<PackageInfo> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            final ArrayList<PackageInfo> pkgs = quickSort(new ArrayList(getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0)));
            for (int i=pkgs.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                Boolean criteria = (pkgs.get(i).applicationInfo.icon==0);
                if (criteria) {
                    pkgs.remove(i);
                }
            }
            return pkgs;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<PackageInfo> pkgs) {
            if (pd!=null) {
                pd.dismiss();
                AlertDialog chooser = new AlertDialog.Builder(mThis)
                        .setAdapter(new AppAdapter(mThis, pkgs), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                String appName = pkgs.get(which).applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
                                Logg.d("selected " + which + "; " + appName);
                                chosenApp.setText(appName);
                                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("ChosenAppPkg", pkgs.get(which).packageName).apply();
                                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("ChosenAppName", appName).apply();
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
            }
        }

    };
    task.execute((Void[])null);

 }
```